# Unable to create a directory in the /data/ partition of the Android

Tags: android, file, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create a partition called "subdata" under "/data". But it's failing.

The steps I tried and the failure results are mentioned below.

```
File dir =new File(/data/subdata/");
boolean success = dir.mkdir();
```

Here, the "success" value is found "false".

```
File dir= context.getDir("/data/subdata",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Here, I get "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_/data/subdata/ contains a path separator`"

Please, help me in creating this subfolder under `/data/` partition.

Comment: maybe you need a root acces or WRITE_PERMISSION_DATA in the manifest

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13845886/1549219

Comment: Iam getting the same java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_/data/subdata/ contains a path separator error

Comment: about that link, iam using that method itslef.. (contex.getDir() )

Comment: What you want would require a rooted device and running commands using `su` or `sudo` or something. You cannot create arbitrary directories in `/data`, as your app does not have write permission to arbitrary locations on that partition.

Comment: no, you cannot make a dir in /data/ if you're device is not rooted, only in the application data directory

Comment: @David mine is rooted. by rooted i mean, i have the android source build and iam making the system apps from that build.

Comment: @CommonsWare , if i create the sub directory myslef through shel terminall, iam able to create and write to files in that directory from my app programatically. so i guess its not the read write access issue. My issue is in creating Directory inside /data/

Comment: @JVN: "so i guess its not the read write access issue" -- yes, it is. `adb shell` operates at superuser privileges, and just because *it* can create a directory, and that your app happens to be able to use that directory, does not mean that your app can create such a directory. "by rooted i mean, i have the android source build and iam making the system apps from that build" -- that has nothing to do with rooting. That being said, it's certainly conceivable that in your custom ROM you can give your system app elevated privileges, such that it can create directories in `/data`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my need in the below manner.

As I mentioned in the question that, if I create the sub folder manually, I'm able to read and write to that subfolder in the `/data`.
So, I created this subfolder through `init.rc` (as I mentioned, I have the build code also). As I'm more fluent in Linux than in Android, I fixed it through `init.rc`. Now I'm able to read/write to that folder through my android code.